# The loop won't restart after it finishes the first if statement. How can I get my loop to restart?

Tags: oop, if-statement, while-loop

My goal in this is to get the Jeroo dale to end of the spiral facing the flower using a loop. The spiral covers the island. Most of the island is covered by 2X2 nets or maybe 1 net and 1 water. The loop won't restart after it finishes the first if statement. How can I get my loop to restart?

The island is covered in a spiral of nets (like a snail shell)

```
method main()
{
Jeroo dale = new Jeroo(0,0);

//While path is clear dale will hop
while(dale.isClear(AHEAD))
  dale.hop();
{
//dale is here if the path ahead is not clear
if( ! dale.isClear(LEFT)){
   dale.turn(RIGHT);
   }
else if(dale.isFlower(RIGHT)){
    dale.turn(RIGHT);       
   }
 else
    dale.turn(LEFT);       
    }        

}
```

Comment: Not knowing the language, removing `dale.hop();`, which I guess is the only statement that will be repeated by the `while`, or movong it to proper place might help. Or just introduce another loop to repeat the process.

Comment: Sorry for misreading. "How can I get my loop to restart?" Just introduce another loop to restart.

Comment: I am using Java/C++/C# Style language

Comment: Apologies - I see now that [Jeroo](http://home.cc.gatech.edu/dorn/jeroo) is an entirely new language. Since yours is the first question *ever* to use it, I doubt it's worth creating a tag for it (currently). I suggest using [tag:algorithm] and [tag:language-agnostic] rather than a quite random language.

Comment: The thing is I am using Jeroo for a school assignment and it is required for us to use it.

Comment: @Alpha : So shouldn't the `{` come before dale.hop() on the while clause. otherwise the code doesn't make sense.

Comment: Is whitespace "free", as it is in the similar languages C++ and Java? (And definitely unlike Python!) If yes, consider [edit]ing your code and adding some indenting to the nested sets of braces.